# Fish keeps trying to use fish_vi_key_bindings although it is not in config.fish anymore

Tags: shell, fish

I am playing with fish and oh-my-fish on the cygwin terminal. It was working fine until I tried to turn on VI key bindings by setting the `fish_vi_key_bindings` in my `config.fish`.

It did not work. Apparently this only works from the version `2.2.x` on, and on cygwin I'm running the version `2.1.1`. Ok, no problem... let's deactivate it by removing that line from the `config.fish`. Currently this file looks like this:

```
# Path to your oh-my-fish.
set fish_path $HOME/.oh-my-fish

# Path to your custom folder (default path is ~/.oh-my-fish/custom)
#set fish_custom $HOME/dotfiles/oh-my-fish

# Load oh-my-fish configuration.
. $fish_path/oh-my-fish.fish

# Custom plugins and themes may be added to ~/.oh-my-fish/custom
# Plugins and themes can be found at https://github.com/oh-my-fish/
Theme 'robbyrussell'
Plugin 'theme'
```

But anyway, when I start the fish console, I get the following message:

```
Welcome to fish, the friendly interactive shell
Type help for instructions on how to use fish
Standard input: begin; fish_vi_key_bindings
                       ^
in . (source) call of file '-',
        called on standard input,

in function '__fish_reload_key_bindings',
        called on line 209 of file '/usr/share/fish/functions/__fish_config_interactive.fish',

in function '__fish_config_interactive',
        called on line 114 of file '/usr/share/fish/config.fish',

in function '__fish_on_interactive',
        called on standard input,

in event handler: handler for generic event 'fish_prompt'
```

And the shell missbehaves completely. I cannot delete what I write, autocomplete does not work, etc. Any help? thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You probably have the universal variable `$fish_key_bindings` set to something you don't want. Try running this (just once):

```
set -U fish_key_bindings fish_default_key_bindings
```